# Couldn't extend session timeout in ZF2

Tags: php, mongodb, session, zend-framework2

I'm saving my session data on my database(mongodb), the customer asked that he want the system   to be idle for 2 hours(he has videos on the site which may take 2 hours to finish, so he asked to set session timeout value as 2 hour). I did it as Zend Framework suggested. see my config.php below

```
return array(
    'env2_session' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
            'options' => array(
                'name' => 'test',
                'remember_me_seconds' => 7200,
                'gc_maxlifetime' => 7200,           
            ),
        ),
        'mongo_handler' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'class' => 'Zend\Session\SaveHandler\MongoDBOptions',
                'collection' => 'sessions',
            ),
        ),
        'save_handler' => 'Env2Session/Mongo/Handler',
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
                'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

But this is not the correct code as I couldn't see the session extended. it still get timed out after 24 minutes.

It will work if I add 'cookie_lifetime' => 7200 after 'gc_maxlifetime' => 7200 But this get timedout even if I'm using the site.

I want the timeout only when the system is idle. Please get me some thing on this.

Here is the save handler code which I written in Module.php

```
    public function getServiceConfig()
        {
            return array(
                'factories' => array(
                    'Env2Session/Mongo/Handler' => function ($sm) {
                        $config = $sm->get('config');
                        $session = $config['env2_session'];

                        $mongo = $sm->get('Env2\Mongo');

                        $class = isset($session['mongo_handler']['options']['class'])  ? $session['mongo_handler']['options']['class'] : 'Zend\Session\SaveHandler\MongoDBOptions';
                        $options = array();
                        $options['collection'] = $session['mongo_handler']['options']['collection'];
                        $options['database'] = $config['db']['mongo']['db_name'];
                        $mongoOption = new $class($options);

                        $sessionSaveHandler = new MongoDB($mongo, $mongoOption);
                        return $sessionSaveHandler;
                    },
                    'Env2Session' => function ($sm) {
                        $config = $sm->get('config');
                        if (isset($config['env2_session'])) {
                            $session = $config['env2_session'];

                            $sessionConfig = null;
                            if (isset($session['config'])) {
                                $class = isset($session['config']['class'])  ? $session['config']['class'] : 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig';
                                $options = isset($session['config']['options']) ? $session['config']['options'] : array();
                                $sessionConfig = new $class();
                                $sessionConfig->setOptions($options);
                            }

                            $sessionStorage = null;
                            if (isset($session['storage'])) {
                                $class = $session['storage'];
                                $sessionStorage = new $class();
                            }
                            $sessionSaveHandler = null;
                            if (isset($session['save_handler'])) {
                                $sessionSaveHandler = $sm->get($session['save_handler']);
                            }

                            $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig, $sessionStorage, $sessionSaveHandler);

                            if (isset($session['validator'])) {
                                $chain = $sessionManager->getValidatorChain();
                                foreach ($session['validator'] as $validator) {
                                    $validator = new $validator();
                                    $chain->attach('session.validate', array($validator, 'isValid'));
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            $sessionManager = new SessionManager();
                        }
                        Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
                        return $sessionManager;
                    }
                ),
            );
        }
```

Comment: You need to set `cookie_lifetime`. If the session timeouts aren't being updated whilst the session is active, that suggests a problem with your save handler. It looks like you're using a custom one - could there be an issue with that?

Comment: I checked my db and corresponding collection and found that each time I traverse from the site, the field "modified" is getting updated. But the timeout value calculation is based on the first value that entered to the "modified", it should be the latest value, is there anything to light me on this point? [I have updated the question with mongo save handler which I have written in Module.php] –

Comment: what is the need of 'cookie_lifetime' as it set browser cookie life time and it will expire in that time interval even if I'm using the website. Please clarify me if I'm wrong

Comment: What is the `MongoDB` class you create an instance of in your code sample?

Comment: class name is vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Session/SaveHandler/MongoDB.php

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue for zend session timeouts. Finally I implemented own solution for this case. I set up the expiration time which is refreshed during each request. But if user is not active, the time will expire and session will be destroyed.

I put all tutorial how to do it here: http://blog.tulikowski.com/zend-framework-2-implementation-of-session-authentication-timeouts/

Comment: Can you please make this a complete answer and not just a pointer to your blog? Answers should stand on their own; your blog post should at best be a place to get more details, not the whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your autoload/global.php and either create or edit this key:

```
        'session_config'    =>  array
                                (
                                    'cache_expire'          =>  60*60*2,
                                    'name'                  =>  'sessionName',
                                    'cookie_lifetime'       =>  60*60*2,
                                    'gc_maxlifetime'        =>  60*60*2,
                                    'cookie_path'           =>  '/',
                                    'cookie_secure'         =>  FALSE,
                                    'remember_me_seconds'   =>  60*60*2,
                                    'use_cookies'           =>  true,
                                ),
```

Comment: This works but I'm getting logged out even when I'm working with the site, it should be logged out only once after the site is idle for 2hrs. I'm updating my question with my save_handler, please add something more on this